How can I trigger hx-post with dynamic url
I'm making a website with HTMX. I usually manage to do what I want with HTMX but I have a problem activating an hx-post with a dynamic URL. I have a list of items that the user must be able to rename and for that I open a modal. When I press the save button of my modal it must activate an hx-post that will send the new name to my API. I need a dynamic URL to have only once the HTML code of my modal without having to hardcode it for each item in the list
Here is the HTML code that I currently have:
<div id="renameModal" class="fixed hidden">
    <div>
        <h2 >Rename Document</h2>
        <form id="renameForm" hx-swap="outerHTML">
            <input type="hidden" id="docIdInput" name="docId" value="">
            <div>
                <label for="nameInput" >New Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="name" class="required">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button" id="cancelButton" >Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" >Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function openRenameModal(docId, docTitle) {
        document.getElementById('renameModal').classList.remove('hidden');
        document.getElementById('docIdInput').value = docId;
        // #title-docId is the id of the p-tag that need to be replace by the api response
        document.getElementById('renameForm').setAttribute('hx-target', '#title-' + docId);
        document.getElementById('renameForm').setAttribute('hx-post', '/document/rename/' + docId);
        document.getElementById('nameInput').value = docTitle;
    }

    document.getElementById('cancelButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('renameModal').classList.add('hidden');
    });

    document.getElementById('renameForm').addEventListener('htmx:afterSwap', function(event) {
        if (event.detail.xhr.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById('renameModal').classList.add('hidden');
        }
    });
</script>

When I press "Save" my modal disappears and I am redirected to <url of my site>/<an ID>?docId=<id of the doc a want to rename>&name=<the new name> while I do not want to be redirected, I just want to make a post request to my api and have the document renamed for the client by what the api returns.
How can I make my site work the way I want it to?

This question is similar to: HTMX: Request not firing when hx attributes are added dynamically from JavaScript function. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The problem is that htmx has to parse the tags before the js can set the attributes dynamically
I solved this problem by making a GET route that returns the modal like that no need to use javascript or make dynamic attributes. It's simpler and easier to code
